# Looping Constructs to create a set of varibale matrices

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I am trying to create an $ n \times n $ matrix, which has cosine terms. I would like to select the values of the arguments of cosine terms from a random set of values that I have generated. My code looks as follows:

```
angles = RandomChoice[ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 2], {2, 3}]

M = Table[If[i == j, 0, Cos[x[i] - x[j]]], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
```

Comment: What is the relation between `x` and your `angles`?

Comment: angles is a set of x[i]'s

Answer (score 1):

I think `DistanceMatrix` constructive here. Consider this:

```
DistanceMatrix[#, DistanceFunction -> Cos@*Subtract] - IdentityMatrix[Length[#]] & /@ angles
```

Comment: I am looking for a generation of a tridiagonal matrix, with off-diagonal terms as functions of x[i]'s like the ones from distance function you've used.